# I would like to use php as proxy server to pass json data to a webservice, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, ajax, json, web-services, proxy

Below is php script I am trying to use as proxy to pass two parameters (username and password) to a web service to return data in json format.

This is a workaround to the famed same domain limitation policy.

I keep getting invalid username or password.

The ajax file is trying to pass two parameters to the webservice via php proxy script.

Here is a snippet of the ajax file:

```
var uname = $("#user").val();
var upass = $("#pass").val();

    $.post("proxyurl.php",
      { data: JSON.stringify({ LoginName: uname,Password: upass }) })
        .done(function(data) {
```

Below is proxyurl.php

```
  <?php

    $ch = curl_init("http://myotherdomain.com/getUserDetails");
    $strUser = $_POST["uname"];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"LoginName=".urlencode($strUser));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);      
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $output
  ?>
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually sending over `LoginName` and `Password` to your proxy script, not `uname`.

As well, curlopt_Postfields is perfectly happy to accept an array of key/value pairs and will encode it for you. There is no need to manually building a `key=value` string yourself.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
```

is technically all you'd really need to do.

Comment: thanks a lot for the prompt response.

I take it that I don't even need this line:

` $strUser = $_POST["uname"];`?

Either way, I am getting `Ajax request failed` with or without the line above>

I got this to work using classic asp but the users wanted php as proxy server.

Comment: does this other server require a login? not the credentials you're sending over, but a separate user/pass to actually access the url?

Comment: never mind sir, it worked beautifully. 

I added one extra ')' in error. 

You are majestic sir.

Thank you very much for your prompt assistance and kindness.